# Finding string in a text file: keeps returning False once the else statement is added

Tags: python

I write a python script to look for a string in a text file. It finds the string without a problem. However, when i add the else statement to return string "not found" in case the string isn't found, the script keeps returning "not found".

I have checked examples on stackoverflow but none of the codes solve my issue.

```py
param = "foo.txt"

def getChannel_range(param):

    param_file = open(param, 'r')
    LINES = param_file.readlines()

    channel_range = 'CHAN_RANGE' #keyword to look for in the text file

    for i in range(len(LINES)):
        line = LINES[i]
        if line.find(channel_range) >=0:
            chan_range = line.partition('=')[2]
        else:
            chan_range = "not found"

    param_file.close()

    return chan_range

chan_range = getChannel_range(param)
print chan_range
```

Actual result "not found". I know the string is in the text. If i don't add the else statement, it finds the string and return it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the result with the else statement

try this:

```
if line.find(channel_range) >=0:
   chan_range = line.partition('=')[2]
   break       
else:
   chan_range = "not found"
```

The issue is that if the file has 5 lines, you are finding the keyword in 3rd line, but not on the 4th line, so you set it to "not found".
"break" exits the loop when you find the result the first time

Comment: Thank you! I should have asked on stackoverflow earlier and save my time.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set chan_range before the for loop and only override it if found:

```
chan_range = "not found"
for i in range(len(LINES)):
        line = LINES[i]
        if line.find(channel_range) >=0:
            chan_range = line.partition('=')[2]
```

Also a few less steps is you can use a while loop with `param_file.readline()`. Then when searching for a string in a string you can do the `if mystring in otherstring:` like the following:

```
param = "foo.txt"

def getChannel_range(param):

    param_file = open(param, 'r')
    line = param_file.readline()

    channel_range = 'CHAN_RANGE' #keyword to look for in the text file
    chan_range = "not found"
    while line:

        if channel_range in line:
            chan_range = line.split('=')[1]
        line = param_file.readline()

    param_file.close()

    return chan_range

chan_range = getChannel_range(param)
print(chan_range)
```

Comment: Thanks. This does shorten the script.